# Civ 5 mods not working on Mac

Tags: civilization-5, mods, macos

I'm trying to use a byzantine mod in Civilization 5 on my Mac (Mountain Lion), but when I put the mod's folder in `~/Documents/Aspyr/Sid Meier's Civilization 5/MODS`, it doesn't sho up in the mod menu. I already have the game set up so I can see `Mods` in the opening screen, but the mods don't show up in installed mods or downloads.

EDIT

I tried it with two different file types, an unarchived .civ5mod file and an unarchived zip file. With the unarchived .civ5mod file, it worked, and the folder only contained 2 files, a .lua and .modinfo. The other one, that didn't work, had a folder in it called XML, and then multiple subfolders, i.e. Civilizations, Buildings ... I want to use those mods, but cannot use it with the subfolders. How would I use those mods? Heres the link to one of the mods. [here](http://forums.civfanatics.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=17156)

Comment: Does this hold true for any other mods? Can you perhaps try it? It would help with the troubleshooting.

Comment: Can you give us a link to where the other one that isn't working can be downloaded, so we can properly investigate what the problem is? It might just be a broken mod.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Heres the link, http://forums.civfanatics.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=17156, I think the problem is there's no modinfo file or something like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you've just installed the mod wrong. Considering the zip's file structure, it's an easy mistake to make.

The zip file has this folder structure ([f]iles and [d]irectories as marked):

```
byzantine mod 2 (v 1).zip
  |
  - [d] Byzantine Mod 2 (v 1)
     |
     - [d] Byzantine Mod
     |  |
     |  - [d] XML
     |     |
     |     + [d] Buildings
     |     + [d] Civilizations
     |     + [d] Leaders
     |     + [d] NewText
     |     + [d] Units
     |
     - [f] Byzantine Mod 2 (v 1).modinfo
```

Notice the `.modinfo` file at the bottom there? That's what you're missing. What you most probably did was copy only the `Byzantine Mod` folder into your `Mods` folder. You should be able to put the whole `Byzantine Mod 2 (v 1)` folder into your `Mods` folder and have it work. Note that this is not the same as putting the `byzantine mod 2 (v 1)` folder or the `Byzantine Mod` folder into your `Mods` folder!

When you have it installed, your folder structure should be:

```
.../Mods
  |
  - [d] Byzantine Mod 2 (v 1)
  |  |
  |  - [d] Byzantine Mod
  |  |  |
  |  |  + [d] XML
  |  - Byzantine Mod 2 (v 1).modinfo
  |
  + [d] some other mod
  + [d] etc
```

... though just putting the `.modinfo` file and its sibling `Byzantine Mod` folder in the `Mods` folder without a containing folder should work too.